How to split console output for input and output streams?
My console application contains several objects, each of which runs in a separate Task. All these objects use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger to print their state to the console. Through the console input stream, I enter commands to control these objects. The thing is, when I enter commands (for example, "stop all"), the console looks like this:
14:43:11 dbug: Program[0] [Object 1] I am Object One!
st14:43:12 info: Program[0] [Object 2] I am Object Two!
14:43:12 info: Program[0] [Object 1] I am Object One!
op 14:43:13 info: Program[0] [Object 3] I am Object Three!
14:43:13 info: Program[0] [Object 2] I am Object Two!
14:43:14 info: Program[0] [Object 3] I am Object Three!
14:43:14 info: Program[0] [Object 1] I am Object One!
al14:43:15 dbug: Program[0] [Object 2] I am Object Two!
l14:43:15 info: Program[0] [Object 1] I am Object One!

The desired behavior is to have a separate line at the bottom of the console buffer that will display the current input from the input stream WHILE I'm typing a command, like this:
14:43:11 dbug: Program[0] [Object 1] I am Object One!
14:43:12 info: Program[0] [Object 2] I am Object Two!
14:43:12 info: Program[0] [Object 1] I am Object One!
14:43:13 info: Program[0] [Object 3] I am Object Three!
14:43:13 info: Program[0] [Object 2] I am Object Two!
14:43:14 info: Program[0] [Object 3] I am Object Three!
14:43:14 info: Program[0] [Object 1] I am Object One!
14:43:15 dbug: Program[0] [Object 2] I am Object Two!
14:43:15 info: Program[0] [Object 1] I am Object One!
Your command >>> stop all

